# Infer interface by type at compile time

Tags: c#, interface, reflection.emit

Is there any way to infer an interface from an object based on its type.  For instance if I had the following object:

```csh
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName
  { get; set; }

  public string LastName
  { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to infer this interface:

```csh
public interface IPerson
{
  string FirstName
  { get; set; }

  string LastName
  { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is be able to create a generic proxy factory, using reflection.emit, that adheres to the inferred interface at compile time.  I know that I could instead return a dynamic object with all the object's properties, but that is all handled at runtime vs. compilation.

**Edit**

A little more explanation for what I'm trying to achieve.  I want to create a proxy class that has a method with a signature something like this:

```csh
public T GetProxyFor<U>(U SomeObject);
```

That way a user can call GetProxyFor(People) and get back a PeopleProxy object that would implement the properties of the People object (or any other object).  That way, someone using this code could call PeopleProxy.LastName and this would successfully compile, but a call to PeopleProxy.Age would result in an error when compiled since it doesn't exist.

I'm fairly new to Reflection and emitting, so what I'm wanting may not be possible.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Are you trying to build a code generator that creates that interface as a codefile? Or are you trying to build an interface on the fly inside of running code? Or something else?

Comment: I recommend T4 for this.

Comment: @JoeEnos, I added an edit to the original post that hopefully explains my question in more detail.

Comment: If your types look like this, wouldn't it make more sense to write the interface and then create the class at runtime?

Comment: I purposely used a simple object only for illustrative purposes.  I plan on my proxy being used generically so there's no way that interfaces can be written for every use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're asking for is to execute some code that creates the interface at compile time.

Your options are:

1. Use something like T4. You can use that to generate C# code based on some input at compile time.
2. Use F# type providers. That's basically exactly what you want: it can execute code at compile time and generate the interface right when you write the code that calls `GetProxyFor()`. But there is nothing like that in C#, so it would require you to switch to F# (at least for the part of your code that uses `GetProxyFor()`).
3. Think about the underlying problem behind this question (which you didn't tell us) and solve it in another way.